# Subclasses and inheritance

Tags: android, inheritance, subclass, superclass

Let's have I have 3 classes. The First one is the parent class, The second one is a subclass of the Parent class. And the third class is a extends the 2nd class, which is a subclass itself. 
Will the 3rd class inherit the methods from the parent class?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and see for yourself? That'll be a nice exercise!

Comment: what´s got to do with Android development?

Comment: well a computer is a Von Neumann machine and you did not tag this with the label

Comment: pitty I cannot downvote it twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best example could be the class all Android developers know : [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

The doc clearly says that **Activity** extends **ContextThemeWrapper** which extends **ContextWrapper** which extends **Context** which extends **Object**.

Object class has ".toString()" method. So, try to print in your console any object you instantiate (like your main Activity) to see the result !

*Everything is Object in Java.*

Now you know. :)